# INA219 current sensor with too much noise and impossibility of with filtering ESP32 + L298 H-bridge

Tags: filter, i2c, signal-processing, esp32, l298

***Hey there***

I have a project involving measuring a DC mini-motor, with a INA 219 sensor. The circuitry is as follows, where "Sensor de corrente" = Ina219 and the "Converter" = L298:

[image]

#### My goal is to execute a frequency test....

This test is usually performed for systems where the output is a current and the transfer function has 2 zeros and 1 pole. Through a standard response test, it is impossible to say the exact location of the system's zero. Therefore, it is necessary to rely on the system's frequency response.

#### Let's tackle the problem:

The code is simple. The general view (refer to the block diagram) is to send duty-cicles references to the ESP32 so that it generates a sinusoidal pwm(spwm).
In this part, the PWM is generated using the MCPWM library (I have also tested with LEDC) and it is generated perfectly. It is then sent to the L298 module, which receives it without any issues.
In the current reading, it is possible to observe a sinusoidal waveform, but it is heavily distorted by noise, despite using a new INA 219 sensor that is correctly connected. The current sampling occurs in a separate loop from the ESP(on core 0), different from the main loop (where the SPWM is generated, on core 1). Initially, the sampling was intended to be at 1kHz, but lower values (e.g., 200Hz) were also tested without significant changes, as follows:

[image]

Fig. 2: Here, we have the reference voltage at 10Hz on the oscilloscope, already filtered with an RC filter (R=10k, C= two parallel 473 disc capacitor).

[image]

Fig. 3:In this one, the INA219 samples are exported through the ESP32 DAC, and FILTERED with the same picture 3 RC filter.

#### Reproductible example:

As said before, we use 2 different loops, with its own delay()-structure. The "main" loop, in the main core (1) makes the duty-cicles changes, through the waveFormTable array. It was designed with a lenght of 100 indexes, but I changed for less points, e.g. LEN = 20, and had too few changes. The duty cycle-range is from 0.6 to 1. The desired sinuisodal output frequency can be changed when the user recalculate the delay inside loop() and compile/run it again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_attr.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "driver/mcpwm.h"
#include "soc/mcpwm_reg.h"
#include "soc/mcpwm_struct.h"
#include "driver/dac.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_INA219.h"

Adafruit_INA219 ina219;
mcpwm_config_t pwm_config;
TaskHandle_t Task1;

#define GPIO1 14                                   //L298 IN1 
#define GPIO2 12                                   //L298 IN2
#define LEN 100
int freq_switch= 20000;                            //freq PWM peripheral

int WaveFormTable[LEN] = {80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,96,97
,98,98,99,99,99,99,99, 100,99,99,99,99,99,98,98,97,96,96
,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86,84,83,82,81,80,79,78,77               
,76,74,73,72,71,70,69,68,67,66,65,64,64,63,62,62,61,61
,61,61,61,60,61,61,61,61,61,62,62,63,64,64,65,66,67,68
,69,70,71,72,73,74,76,77,78,79};
int indexTb = 0;                                   //sweeps the table
```

Continuing with the code, we have the following function that runs on core 0, reading the current and exporting it to the DAC:

```
void read_ina (void * pvParameters){
     for(;;){
           //  Serial.print(ina219.getCurrent_mA());
           //  Serial.print("\n");
           dacWrite(25,int(abs(ina219.getCurrent_mA())));   
           delay(1);                           //1kHz sampling
    }
}
```

Below, some parameters are configured: baudrate, PWM frequency (also tested with 5kHz, 10kHz, unfortunately without significant changes), and the complementary PWM to drive mini-motor with the L298N full bridge.And In the loop() function, the duty cycle change routine is implemented as previously explained.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(read_ina, "Task1", 10000, NULL, 0, &Task1, 0 );

  /*MCPWM*/
  mcpwm_gpio_init(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM0A, GPIO1);
  mcpwm_gpio_init(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM0B, GPIO2);
  pwm_config.frequency = freq_switch;    
  pwm_config.counter_mode = MCPWM_UP_COUNTER;
  pwm_config.duty_mode = MCPWM_DUTY_MODE_0;
  mcpwm_init(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM_TIMER_0, &pwm_config); 

  mcpwm_deadtime_enable(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM_TIMER_0, MCPWM_ACTIVE_HIGH_COMPLIMENT_MODE, 0, 0);  //Enable deadtime on PWM0A and PWM0B with red = (656)*100ns & fed = (67)*100ns on PWM0A and PWM0B generated from PWM0A  
  
  /*SENSOR*/
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {;} 
    if (! ina219.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find INA219 chip");
    while (1) { delay(10); }
  }
}

void loop()
{                               
    pwm_config.cmpr_a = WaveFormTable[indexTb];
    mcpwm_init(MCPWM_UNIT_0, MCPWM_TIMER_0, &pwm_config);   
    indexTb++;   
    if(indexTb == LEN)
      indexTb = 0;
  delayMicroseconds(100);                      
}
```

That's all, friends! I really need suggestions, tips, opinions, anything. I have been stuck on this project for weeks and I can't progress from this point. I have never seen such distortion in the INA219, even though I have worked with it without issues in previous projects.

Comment: how are you? Did you have any progress with this problem? I'm at the same point, a very similar project. The only thing I haven't tried yet is to isolate "the" GND. Maybe with a 1:1 high frequency transformer.